# How Do I Query 7 Days Ago in Shopify Graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify

I'm trying to query order data in the past 7 days with graphql for shopify. My query successfully pulls all order data but I'm having trouble narrowing down the date range.

This query works for all data:

```
 const currentOrders = await client.query({
      data: {
        query: GET_ALL_LINE_ITEMS,
        variables: { endCursor },
      },
    });

const GET_ALL_LINE_ITEMS = `
query storeOrders($endCursor: String) {
  orders(first:25, reverse:true, sortKey: CREATED_AT, after: $endCursor) {
    edges {
      node {
        lineItems(first: 10) {
          edges{
            node {
              name
              quantity
              variantTitle
              variant {
                id 
                product {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage, endCursor
    }
  }
}
`;
```

This is the query I've created to get the last 7 days:

```
  let date = new Date();
  let sevenDaysAgo = date - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1; 
  sevenDaysAgo = new Date(sevenDaysAgo);

  let dd = String(sevenDaysAgo.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  let mm = String(sevenDaysAgo.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); 
  let yyyy = sevenDaysAgo.getFullYear();

  sevenDaysAgo = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
 
    const currentOrders = await client.query({
      data: {
        query: GET_ALL_LINE_ITEMS,
        variables: { endCursor, sevenDaysAgo },
      },
    });

const GET_ALL_LINE_ITEMS = `
query storeOrders($endCursor: String) {
  orders(first:25, query:"created_at:>'$sevenDaysAgo'", reverse:true, sortKey: CREATED_AT, after: $endCursor) {
    edges {
      node {
        lineItems(first: 10) {
          edges{
            node {
              name
              quantity
              variantTitle
              variant {
                id 
                product {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage, endCursor
    }
  }
}
`;
```

It runs, however, the date is not respected and results before the request date are shown.

This is what the [Shopify docs](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-07/queries/orders#examples-Get_the_first_10_orders_updated_after_December_1__2019) says:

```
{
  orders(first: 10, query:"created_at:>2019-12-01") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        updatedAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I pull all graphql results after a given date?

EDIT:

Doing the following query works to this tells me it is an issue with the variable:

```
const GET_ALL_LINE_ITEMS = `
query storeOrders($endCursor: String) {
  orders(first:25, query:"updated_at:>2019-12-01", reverse:true, sortKey: CREATED_AT, after: $endCursor) {
    edges {
      node {
        lineItems(first: 10) {
          edges{
            node {
              name
              quantity
              variantTitle
              variant {
                id 
                product {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage, endCursor
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use single quotes in the query and that seems to do the trick for me.

{
"query": "created_at:>'2022-03-28'"
}

Comment: So the issue I'm running into is that the variable `$sevenDaysAgo` is not being respected. In the query, it's be interpreted as a string with the value being `"$sevenDaysAgo"` vs being a variable. Any idea how to get the variable to work properly?

Comment: JS uses introspection like `${}` ... so backticks, dollar sign, squiggly brackets and the name of the variable. Not like you trying just the dollar sign. JS is not PHP

Comment: I'm following the convention used from Shopify's Node CLI code for Graphql requests with variables: ```const RECURRING_PURCHASE_MUTATION = `
  mutation test(
    $name: String!
    $lineItems: [AppSubscriptionLineItemInput!]!
    $returnUrl: URL!
    $test: Boolean
  ) {
    appSubscriptionCreate(
      name: $name
      lineItems: $lineItems
      returnUrl: $returnUrl
      test: $test
    ) 
  }
`;
```
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-node/blob/cli_three/web/helpers/ensure-billing.js

Comment: OK. Well, you're 99% there then.

Comment: It's just that last 1% giving me trouble haha

Comment: Probably a typo. You can do it.